# Grouping visits by a number ID

Tags: google-analytics

I want to group visits by certain id number because every id represents a different client (think of a subdomain or something like that), for example:

```
http://site.com/234/home
http://site.com/234/search/something
```

are URL's for client **234**, while...

```
http://site.com/155/home
http://site.com/155/search/something
```

are URL's for client **155**.

I'm a total noob on this, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one way permanent way to do this that that doesn't require you to change the tracking code in your markup is ***Advanced Segments***.

Advantages of this technique in your case:

- You can create each segment and given
  them descriptive names (e.g., client
  id);
- Unlike, for instance, using an
  Advanced Filter, the Advanced
  Segments are active immediately (as
  soon as you create them) and they
  don't permanently alter your data.

Advanced Segments are simple to configure. This [Post](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108040) by the GA Team is an excellent step-by-step guide, or you can follow these two consecutive screen shots below:

Step 1: click *Advanced Segments* in the upper right-hand corner from the Dashboard view then click *Create a new advanced segment* when you see the view below:

[image]

There are a number of ways to configure your Advanced Segment; here i've chosen the *Page Dimension* from *Content* then selected Condition *Contains* then just key in a value for a path that distinguishes each client ID.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No exactly what you asked, but you can go to:

1. Content
2. Content Drilldown
3. See the aggregated unique pageviews and other info for each client /id/